# Math "f" in mtpro2

Tags: math-mode, italic, mtpro

I'm aware that this might not be a very transcendental question, but I've noticed something very particular with the math fonts in mtpro2. It turns out that the letter "f" is slightly different displayed when using math mode in comparison with the emphasis or italic modes. In the first one, the "f" is larger and wider. Of course, the difference is very subtle, but honestly I prefer the italic version. Is there a way to set the math letters to have the italic shape? Thanks in advance. [image]

Pd: The same occurs with "u" and "v". This case is more clear.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I won't comment on the *f*, but there's a good reason that the math *v* has a different shape: consider the shape of `\nu`.  Times italic *v* and `\nu` are too easily confused; Knuth addressed this problem in Computer Modern by just making all italic *v*s rounded at the bottom.

Comment: you see the same with almost all math fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but in Computer Modern, the math font is the same as the italic font. What I see is that in mtpro2 the math and italic fonts are not quite the same

Comment: no! cm math italic is not the same as the text italic, it has a wider f and modified v and wider sidebearings generally.

Comment: @EstebanSaldarriaga `\it`  and `\teni`  ie cmit and cmmit fonts [in plain tex look at the f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZW2e.png)

Answer (score 8):

The MTPro2 fonts don't provide a text font and you have to supply a clone of Times yourself.

With `newtxtext` we can compare the height of a math and a text italic x to get

[image]

respectively. OK, let's apply a magnification by a factor 1.0316

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=1.0316]{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

$f$\textit{f}

\sbox0{$x$}\the\ht0

\sbox0{\itshape x}\the\ht0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now text italic and math italic have the same height and, indeed, the two *f* letters are comparable in vertical size. Not in precise shape, but that's common for math fonts, as barbara beeton remarks.

It's not so difficult to change the round math italic v into the text italic v or to borrow it from `newtxmath`. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: +1 for the `scale=1.0316` option. It's worth noting that this works not only for the `f` glyph, but for virtually all other Latin-alphabet glyphs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show the difference between text italic and math in Computer Modern. Most (all?) letters have slightly different shape.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\ooalign{\hfil$b$\hfil\cr\hfil\textcolor{red}{\textit{b}}\hfil\cr}%
\ooalign{\hfil$c$\hfil\cr\hfil\textcolor{red}{\textit{c}}\hfil\cr}%
\ooalign{\hfil$g$\hfil\cr\hfil\textcolor{red}{\textit{g}}\hfil\cr}%
\ooalign{\hfil$m$\hfil\cr\hfil\textcolor{red}{\textit{m}}\hfil\cr}

\end{document}
```